# How clear form after submit

Tags: javascript, dom

I made some little project with adding element to DOM. It's working but I don't know how to clear form after submit. I need to assign a blank value? At what point? Sorry, Im new, please don't bite. Thanks.

```js
const addElement = (e, node, txt, attr, value) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const element = document.createElement(node); 
    if(txt){
        const text = document.createTextNode(txt); 
        element.appendChild(text); 
    }
    if(attr){
        element.setAttribute(attr, value)
    }
    document.querySelector('.content').appendChild(element);
}

const addForm = document.querySelector('.form--add');
addForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => addElement(
    e, 
    addForm.elements.node.value,
    addForm.elements.text.value,
    addForm.elements.attr.value,
    addForm.elements.value.value,
));
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
    <form class="form form--add"> 
        <h1 class="form__title">Add element to DOM</h1>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" name="node" placeholder="element html" required>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" name="text" placeholder="txt in element html">
        <input type="text" class="form__input" name="attr" placeholder="attr" required>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" name="value" placeholder="attr value" required>
        <button class="form__button">Add element</button>
    </form>
    <form class="form form--search"> 
        <h1 class="form__title">Search DOM</h1>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="szukana nazwa elementu" required>
        <input type="submit" class="form__button" value="znajdź i pokaż informacje">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<footer class="footer">Stopka</footer>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Thank you

Comment: When you submit form input.value = "'

Comment: Did you try `addForm.reset();`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: what you describe is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `addForm.reset()`

or

declare an id for suppose form_id then paste below code after submit

```
document.getElementById("form_id ").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => addElement(
      e,
      addForm.elements.node.value,
      addForm.elements.text.value,
      addForm.elements.attr.value,
      addForm.elements.value.value,
      addForm.getElementsByTagsName('input').forEach(el => {
        el.value = ''
      })
    ));
```